# How to analyse Jmeter response by external C/Go/Java program

Tags: java, c, go, jmeter

How the extracted JSON o/p of Jmeter response to be fed to external Go/C/Java application?

My requirement is to analyze the o/p of Jmeter by external program and log the analysis result ( o/p of external program), basically Jmeter response will provide input parameters to the external program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save response of a JMeter's [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) into a file - just add [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener and specify the desired file location:

Example configuration:

[image]

Once you run your request and get the response - JMeter will store it into a file under the given path so you will be able to "feed" it to an external program. See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more details if needed.

If you want to perform the analysis within the bounds of the JMeter test execution - you can invoke this 3rd-party program via [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)